# Java generic type inference

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, type-inference

I am trying to pass

`Map<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>> variable`

to super class's constructor that expects:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List>>
```

I tried changing parent class's constructor to expect

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<?>>>
```

and

```
Map<String, Map<String, ? extends List>>
```

to no avail.

Comment: if you try this :Map<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>>

Comment: Modify the superclass to use generics properly!

Comment: @LouisWasserman If you referring to binding List to specific type, that is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can change the superclass constructor signature; you just need something that accepts an arbitrary value for the `List` element type?

That should probably be `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, ? extends List<?>>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will "help" a litle

```
static void test(Map<String, Map<String, List>> m) {
    System.out.println(m);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>> variable = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>>();
    Map<String, Map<String, List>> m2=(Map)variable;
    test(m2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that capture conversion is not applied recursively:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10

so '?' within nested < > is ignored for capture conversion

one way (although not completely satisfactory from the point of view of getting any value from generics) to make your code work would be to do something like:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Foo extends FooParent {
    Foo(Map<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>> variable) {
        super(variable);
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>> var =
            new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<TranslationImport>>>();
        Foo foo = new Foo(var);
    }
}

class FooParent {
    FooParent(Map<String, ?> variable) {
        System.out.println("FooParent constructor");
    }
}

class TranslationImport {
}
```